# What is the difference between λ and Λ with regard to molar conductivity?

Tags: electrochemistry, notation, conductivity

I came across these equations (boxed in red) in a book:

> $$
> \begin{align}
> &\therefore & t_\mathrm{c} &= \frac{u_\mathrm{c}}{u_\mathrm{c} + u_\mathrm{a}}\\
> &\text{and} & t_\mathrm{a} &= \frac{u_\mathrm{a}}{u_\mathrm{c} + u_\mathrm{a}}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   At infinite dilution,
>   $$\text{Also,} \quad t_\mathrm{c}^\infty = \frac{u_\mathrm{c}^\infty}{u_\mathrm{c}^\infty + u_\mathrm{a}^\infty}$$
>   Since, $\lambda_\mathrm{c}^\infty = u_\mathrm{c}^\infty\times F$ and $\lambda_\mathrm{a}^\infty = u_\mathrm{a}^\infty\times F$
>   $$
> \bbox[3px,border:1px solid red]{
> \begin{align}
> &\therefore & t_\mathrm{c}^\infty \times \Lambda_\mathrm{elecrolyte}^\infty &= \lambda_\mathrm{c}^\infty\\
> &\text{and} & t_\mathrm{a}^\infty \times \Lambda_\mathrm{elecrolyte}^\infty &= \lambda_\mathrm{a}^\infty
> \end{align}
> }
> $$

Where $t$ refers to the transport number of an ion, and the subscripts $\mathrm{a}$ and $\mathrm{c}$ refer to an anion and cation, respectively.

From what I've learnt, the uppercase lambda $\Lambda$ refers to molar conductivity. But then what does the lowercase lambda $\lambda$ stand for?

Different sections within the same book give different definitions for $\lambda$, one being 'ionic *conductance*' and another being 'ionic *conductivity*', and I'm pretty sure 'conductance' and 'conductivity' are **not** the same thing.

I *did* try looking it up online, but Wikipedia wasn't much help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in the Wikipedia article [Ion transport number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_transport_number).

Lower case lambda, $\lambda$, is the *molar ionic conductivity*

Upper case lambda, $\Lambda$, is the *molar conductivity*.

$\lambda = t \dfrac{\Lambda}{\nu}$

Where $\nu$ is the number of ions for the cation or anion in the molecule. So $\ce{Na3PO4}$ would have 3 cations per molecule, but only 1 anion per molecule.